# Decorating a module on import without affecting functions implemented in terms of other functions

Tags: python, wrapper, decorator

I've got an interface that I'm working with to declares several verification methods. For simplicity's sake, we can consider three methods. `verify_less_than()`, `verify_equal()`, and `verify_less_than_equal(`). (See below for an implementation). When I import these, I would like to decorate them such that if a verification fails - `verify_less_than( 10, 5 )` - an exception will be raised.

I've got this working for the first two, but the third function is giving me a much harder time. Because `verify_less_than_equal` is defined in terms of the previous two methods, if the first call fails - `verify_less_than_equal( 5, 5 )` - an exception will be thrown before the second gets called.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Example code:

### module.py

```
class needs_decoration():
    def verify_less_than( self, x, y ):
        return( x < y )

    def verify_equal( self, x, y ):
        return( x == y )

    def verify_less_than_equal( self, x, y ):
        return( self.verify_less_than( x, y ) or self.verify_equal( x, y ) )
```

### implementation.py

```
import types
import module

def decorate( fn ):
    def wrapped( self, x, y ):
        res = fn( self, x, y )
        if res == False:
            raise Exception( 'Verification failed!' )
        return res
    return wrapped

for k, v in vars( module.needs_decoration ).items():
    if isinstance( v, types.FunctionType ):
        if not '__init__' in str( vars( module.needs_decoration )[ k ] ):
            vars( module.needs_decoration )[ k ] = decorate( v )

verifier = module.needs_decoration()
verifier.verify_less_than_equal( 5, 5 ) # This will raise an exception, and I would like it not to
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to go with exceptions instead of Booleans?

Comment: You cannot do what you want without intimate knowledge of how the methods are implemented or lookup up the stack to see if you are currently inside another decorated call. This gets ugly fast.

Comment: @joel Absolutely I am. This is hopefully going to be used in an automated test setting. So when an exception is encountered, control will return to the high level controller where it can decide if the failing test portion should be re-run. Using exceptions makes the control a lot cleaner (having to wrap each verification call - hundreds of them - would just clutter the test).

Comment: This seems more likely to cause bugs than to fix them. What if your code relies on the verification *not* throwing those errors?

Comment: @user2357112 Our test is considered failed if one of our verification steps fail, so anything that happens after a verification fails is irrelevant. By throwing the exception, we bypass waiting until the end of the test (several hours later) and can evaluate the situation immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define private (underscored) methods which will remain undecorated, so that `_verify_less_than_equal` can call the undecorated functions. The `for-loop` then can add the public API (methods without underscores) which are decorated versions of the private methods:

```
import types

def add_decorators(cls):
    def decorate(fn):
        def wrapped(self, x, y):
            res = fn(self, x, y)
            if not res:
                raise ValueError('Verification failed! {}({}, {}) is False'
                                .format(fn.__name__, x, y))
            return res
        return wrapped

    for k, v in vars(cls).items():
        if isinstance(v, types.FunctionType):
            if k.startswith('__'): continue
            if k.startswith('_'):
                setattr(cls, k[1:], decorate(v))
    return cls

@add_decorators
class NeedsDecoration():
    def _verify_less_than(self, x, y):
        return x < y

    def _verify_equal(self, x, y):
        return x == y

    def _verify_less_than_equal(self, x, y):
        return self._verify_less_than(x, y) or self._verify_equal(x, y)

    def __init__(self): pass
verifier = NeedsDecoration()
assert verifier.verify_less_than_equal(5, 5)
```

As desired, the last line does not raise an exception.

Comment: This is certainly doable, but having to use different method names is slightly less than ideal.